# Why does SQLite min() function does not work in this query?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Lets say there is a table of price submissions that consist of rowId, shopID, goodID, price, submission time. I'm trying to retrieve the oldest price submission in a given shop. My query looks like this:

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM price_submissions WHERE validshop = '-Kcq2pOeJA2_URuJLFKC' AND submissiondateandtime = (SELECT min(submissiondateandtime) FROM price_submissions)", null);
```

This query returns 0 results. Though if I replace part `(SELECT min(submissiondateandtime) FROM price_submissions)`  with actual min (oldest) value, it does return a row.

Why doesn't the initial query work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT min(submissiondateandtime) FROM price_submissions` returns the oldest price submission not in the given shop, as you write in the textual description, but in the whole table. You might have meant `SELECT * FROM price_submissions AS outer WHERE validshop = '-Kcq2pOeJA2_URuJLFKC' AND submissiondateandtime = (SELECT min(submissiondateandtime) FROM price_submissions AS inner WHERE inner.validshop = outer.validshop)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my issue! Though at the moment I dont understand these commands "AS outer" and "AS inner", but I think I could update my problematic part to `(SELECT min(submissiondateandtime) FROM price_submissions WHERE validshop = '-Kcq2pOeJA2_URuJLFKC')`

Comment: `AS outer` and `AS inner` assign aliases to the two instances of the table, so that it would be unambiguous which column is referred in each case. Your approach is also OK, but you have to write the same identifier twice (which is error-prone when you want to switch to another shop, for example). Aliases allow writing the identifier in one place only, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

First run SELECT min(submissiondateandtime) FROM price_submissions and store min value in one varaiable X then use it in parent query  SELECT * FROM price_submissions WHERE validshop = '-Kcq2pOeJA2_URuJLFKC' AND submissiondateandtime=X

Comment: I was going to use this approach if nothing else works. But I think SQLite should support nested queries like this.